# how to convert to host byte order using lua in wireshark

Tags: lua, wireshark, endianness

I am getting no luck searching for a standard function to do byte-order conversion to write a lua plug-in for wireshark.

struct.pack doesn't seem to work, at least when doing "require 'struct'", wireshark throws an error.

You can call tvb functions to get an explicit (that's what I am doing now so it's not portable :((( ) conversion to either big endian or little endian, but nothing to the host endian byte order.

I searched and searched online but nothing came up so I am hoping someone can offer a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241799/lua-dealing-with-non-ascii-byte-streams-byteorder-change

Comment: Thanks, I tried importing the struct module, but wireshark threw an error.  I didn't explore further and just assumed that it's not available with the lua interpreter built into wireshark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it enough if you can determine the endianness of the system you are running on?

In Lua 5.1 and 5.2 at least, the 7th byte of the bytecode header is 1 for little endian systems and 0 for big endian systems. You can obtain this byte from any Lua script this way:

```
string.dump(function() end):byte(7)
```

If you use LuaJIT you can just check the value of:

```
ffi.abi("le")
```

Finding this out should be enough to let you write portable code.

Comment: nice one-liner.  It works for the lua plug-in for wireshark.  Yes, as long as I know the endianness of the system, I can call the right conversion function.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Wireshark is close to supporting struct.unpack way of doing things.  It's not out on a stable release yet.

http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/32715/no-struct-support-in-wireshark-1107s-lua-interpreter